# Why are different tags shown on the tab for different questions having more than one tag?

Tags: support, tags

Consider Questions [A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078033/lseek-not-working#27078071),[B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078094/systemverilog-dpi-c-pointers),[C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078072/c-programming-getline-function-not-working) and [D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078072/c-programming-getline-function-not-working).All of them are tagged with more than one tag.When I open each one of them,I see one of the tags on the respective tabs (see the screenshot in which tags are circled in red).[image: tags in tabs]

- Is any criteria in which they appear (like number of followers/number
  of questions etc)?
- Also,when I open a question tagged with only one tag,the tag does not appear in the question.Why?

Comment: The tag are added based on question count, highest first, based on this MSE question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87508/are-the-tags-shown-in-a-particular-order   In the tab you see the first tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first tag (sorted by popularity) is prepended, provided it isn't already present in the title itself.

Also see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) on Meta.SE:

> Note that the system automatically prefixes the title with the most common tag (unless it's already in the title somewhere) to help search engines find it more easily.