# Should the first tag be removed from the HTML title?

Tags: discussion

One thing that annoys me with stackoverflow is that the first tag of a question is used to prefix the title (i'm talking about the HTML `<title>` here). When I have several tabs the only thing I see is `javascript-s`,`javascript-g` at a glance which is not really helpful.

So, should the first tag be removed from the HTML title? Would it have SEO ramifications?

[image: Google Chrome 43.0.2357.130]

Related:

- [[SE:Webmasters] - Does the order of keywords matter in a page title?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/does-the-order-of-keywords-matter-in-a-page-title)
- [Remove the most popular tag from the title using JavaScript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71951/remove-the-most-popular-tag-from-the-title-using-javascript)

Comment: This is partically annoying since the tags usually are not in order of relevance so a question purely about database design might be tagged javascript or  a "nonsense" tag like "page" or "form".

Comment: I don't see this in my browser (IE11)... can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Added screenshot @rene. Also I'm not sure about the heuristics of when the its prefixed with the tag - the fourth browser tab is not prefixed for some reason even though that question has tags.

Comment: AFAIK, the tag is added to the title if the title doesn't mention any of the major tags.

Comment: I try to find consistency between title with tag and without...I failed... but I did find [this MSE duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71951/remove-the-most-popular-tag-from-the-title-using-javascript)

Comment: @AndrewT. and what are major tags?

Comment: Next you'll be asking us to remove the leading "Should the" from some question titles because it is not clear enough when you've overburdened your tag bar.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71906/first-tag-in-the-title-of-the-page-is-not-that-convenient/71950#71950

Comment: @rene "_I try to find consistency between title with tag and without...I failed_" -- Maybe [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277632/why-are-different-tags-shown-on-the-tab-for-different-questions-having-more-than) could help?

Comment: Hmm, I see I also commented on your question. Something with bells and ringing .... the answer of martijn explains it clearly. Tnx @CoolGuy

Comment: A userscript would be a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## NO

Jeff Atwood answers is it very well [SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71906/first-tag-in-the-title-of-the-page-is-not-that-convenient/71950#71950).

> Sorry, this is absolutely necessary, otherwise we get demolished by
>   scrapers using our own content in Google ranking.

Unfortunately it is not possible either to reverse the order:

```
How do I update a page with ajax [HTML, PHP, Javascript]
```

Since [keyword order](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/does-the-order-of-keywords-matter-in-a-page-title) is significant.

Comment: I would have voted to close my own question as a duplicate of the MSE question but questions can only be duplicates of other questions on the same network.

Comment: Questions don't need to be closed simply for duplicating something on MSE. Linking to MSE and answering it here is fine, is my understanding.

Comment: Hm, that answer is from 2010. Do you think this is still valid? Search engines do grow better.

Comment: @Bergi I don't know what the rules are specifically but I was assume that most any SEO advice from more than 4 years ago at the very least needs to be reevaluated before being accepted as valid. I'm very skeptical that any of this is still valid.

Comment: Ok, those SEO reports were updated in 2013: https://moz.com/search-ranking-factors/survey#page-level-keyword-usage. Having the keyword as the first word in the `<title>` did still have some moderate importance, but less importance than having the keyword in the `<title>` at all.

Comment: It is 2022, is this still relevant reason? I have three tabs in my browser where I see "Javascr" only. That is annoying and not useful at all. Pleaseeeee.