# Has the time come for SE to stop adding the first tag to the question page's <title> element?

Tags: discussion, seo

Years ago Stack Overflow started to include the first tag from the question in the `<title>` tag. This was done to help with SEO:

Jeff Atwood [SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71906/first-tag-in-the-title-of-the-page-is-not-that-convenient/71950#71950):

> Sorry, this is absolutely necessary, otherwise we get demolished by
>   scrapers using our own content in Google ranking.

This is an understandable reasoning at that time.

[In 2015 there was a request to have this removed because it impacts usability.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297977/should-the-first-tag-be-removed-from-the-html-title)

Three years later I'd like to make a new take at this. **Should the tag be removed from the page title?**

Comment: I started using it in Google queries a while ago.  Worked quite well, still does today.

Comment: is duckduckgo affected with this?

Comment: Note that the current consensus says that don't include tags in title (if you decide to do anyway, make it fit in the sentence). If this is changed a lot of changes may be necessary.

Comment: @user202729 This isn't about putting the tag in the *question's* title when editing. It's about SE prepending the primary tag to the question's actual title in the `<title>` element when rendering the HTML page.

Comment: @Makyen Which is what I was talking about. Normally question title is "How do I declare arrays?", tagged with [c] and the <title> is "c - How do I declare arrays?" which can be understood. If the <title> is "How do I declare arrays?" somebody needs to `[edit]` it to "How do I declare arrays in C?". For many existing questions.

Comment: @user202729 Ahh, then, IMO, the second sentence of your earlier comment is unclear. Your use of "this" would normally pick up the most recent thing that you've talked about, which is "include tags in title" (a significant topic on SO/Meta, as you know). I can see how you meant "this" to mean the proposal here, but it appears ambiguous. Or, perhaps, I just end up editing too many tags out of titles, such that it's a frustration that got triggered.

Comment: Does anyone have a usable question/answer that explains the problem? All answers I can find contain is a bunch of links to some forum discussions, where presumably the real answer is.

Comment: I actually use this because I have a lot of tabs open and I can tell what the specific SE tab is about since the actual question wording may not make that obvious.

Comment: @Elin ["Frustrating when search engine algorithms encourage sites to degrade general web experience"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/does-the-order-of-keywords-matter-in-a-page-title#comment6768_6570).

Answer (score 29):

I'm not so sure about this.

In some cases, removing it could be good.

In other cases, removing it could be somewhere between bad and very bad.

Consider titles like:

- [How to sort an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252269/how-to-sort-an-arraylist)
- [Avoiding != null statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements)
- [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)
- [Create ArrayList from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/create-arraylist-from-array)
- [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

All of these are highly specific to the language, yet none of them actually tell you which language they're actually about based on the title alone. ArrayLists, dictionaries and null exist in multiple languages - whether or not people know this, they may be a bit more hesitant to click on such links, and instead just go for the link which has a big "this is about the language you're working in" indicator right there in the title (although maybe it's worth testing this assumption, if this hasn't been done already).

Now of course this isn't a perfect system, especially in the case of less popular tags, where something like [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) could end up being the primary tag, instead of the language. But removing the tag only indirectly fixes this problem, where a more fundamental change to the tag system might be a better fix.

---

Also, I'm no SEO specialist, but I'm pretty sure title is still a significant contributor to ranking (even if we ignore the whole people-not-clicking-on-the-link problem mentioned above) - if we drop what's arguably the most important term in a lot of cases from the title, that'll presumably push Stack Overflow further down in the results (at least in cases where it only outranks another result by a narrow margin).

---

For [your specific example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43000520/why-would-one-use-taskt-over-valuetaskt-in-c), I agree that the tag shouldn't be there, but this is a bit of a special case.

Should we be including the second tag when the first tag appears in the title? Do we include the third one if both of the first two appear? Those are questions worth investigating.

Comment: I think these are pretty rare cases where a tag in the title is needed to disambiguate. Also, the user can search for "ArrayList .net".

Comment: A compromise would be to move the tag to the end of the title so that it does not look so bad.

Comment: @usr Including a language tag in your search doesn't guarantee that all results will be about that language. Not to mention that what users "can" do is not so relevant as what users *actually* do.

Comment: Couldn’t the tag be added at the end? In cases where you can’t see the whole title (like browser tabs) it doesn’t take up any space but it’s still there for Google.

Comment: @11684 It would probably get cut off a lot of the time, in which case it *would* help with SEO, but it wouldn't help with people just clicking on links featuring the name of the language they're looking for.

Comment: @usr I think it's more common than that.  Despite including "C#" in my google searches I frequently get results for javascript or other languages and have to look at the tag in titles to figure out which ones are actually relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the time has come to do it. Googles algorithms are more sophisticated now. Google even did an [algorithm update](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/algorithm-change-launched/) to specifically help Stack Overflow defend against scraper sites.

I propose that for a random selection of 1% of questions the tag be removed. A month after that the traffic impact can be statistically analyzed.

It might even help traffic because currently the search results for Stack Overflow look a bit spammy due to the tag:

[image]

It looks like a carelessly done spam site, or like the name of the website is "asynchronous".

This might cause users to not click on this result. Google is known to measure user behavior and rank based on it.

Comment: How do you know that google updated their algorithms to help SO deal with scraper sites? If there are any articles or blogs published about it, you should link them

Comment: I can't find it right now. I don't think it was the Panda update although that surely targeted shallow content sites. There was another one. It was done because Stack Overflow was such a visible case of Googles algorithm failing.

Comment: @Rainbacon [Here's the post by Matt Cutts](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/algorithm-change-launched/) (who used to be the head of Google’s webspam team) that mentions the algorithm update that usr is talking about.

Comment: In this particular case the problem is not that the tag is prefixed, the problem is the top tag that is *not included* is appended. If the question only has [c#] no tag would be appended, if it has both tags *but* "in C#" is not already included in the title, then the title will correctly be "c# - how can I ..." ---- a much better way to resolve this is to **not prepend any tag at all if the top tag is already included in the title**. You can make that a FR, with reasoning like the above.